# Difference between Mosfet and Voltage Regulator?

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator

I'm new to electronics and was wondering what was the difference between a Mosfet and a voltage regulator?

Comment: Short answer would be: Almost everything :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MOSFETs and voltage regulators often come in similar-looking packages and usually have 3 pins each, but their functions are different.

A voltage regulator takes in a high voltage, like 12 V, and puts out a lower voltage, like 5 V. The canonical example of a voltage regulator is the [LM7805](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/LM/LM7805.html). They tend to be fairly inefficient (some of the power is lost as heat).

A MOSFET is a semiconductor switch. It varies the resistance between two pins in response to a voltage on a third pin. Inside the MOSFET, the voltage on the third pin (the gate) pulls electrons into a narrow path between the other two pins (the source and drain), allowing electricity to flow. Here's [a decent diagram](http://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/~www_pa/Scots_Guide/first11/part9/page4.html).

Comment: Their inefficiency is directly related to the voltage drop across the regulator. Therefore, the efficiency is **entirely** a function of application, and it not something you can make a blanket statement about. I regularly use linear regulators to regulate a noisy ~6v down to 5v.  That's a efficiency of ~80%, which is as good as a switcher generally gets.

Comment: @Fake Name: You're right that with a low-dropout regulator, you can get higher efficiency performance. But I think that when you're answering a question about the difference between a MOSFET and voltage regulator, it's reasonable to say that regulators tend to be less efficient compared to switchers, without going into the details. I'll change "half" to "some."

Answer (score 7):

In very basic terms, a voltage regulator is a device for building a power supply, whereas a mosfet is something you use to build an amplifier. A voltage regulator is basically an integrated circuit that has several transistors within it, while a mosfet is exactly a single transistor.

Comment: If you view the input power as a signal floating on a DC bias, then a voltage regulator is acting like a filter that attenuates (as opposed to amplifying) fluctuations in the power signal. A poor man's voltage regulator is a single zener diode: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode#Uses

Comment: @eryksun: indeed, though I was just attempting to split the difference w/o going into all the possibilities. I didn't think describing a regulator as an amplifier with zero bandwidth would help a beginner (note tag) to get oriented.

Answer (score 6):

A MOSFET is a single transistor that will be able to provide a regulated voltage if used inside of a whole voltage regulator circuit (or IC). To build a (linear) voltage regulator, one needs a pass element (regulated "valve", e.g. MOSFET or biolar transistor), a voltage reference and a circuit that compares the desired, regulated output voltage to the reference voltage and adjusts the pass element such that the output will remain in regulation.

Thus, a MOSFET may act as one part inside of a voltage regulator.